# Regex match first 4 characters of 2 variables

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match the first 7 characters of 2 variables

```
$a = AB000110
$b = AB000111
```

The above variables when matched should return true. I searched and found this solution

```
if (preg_match("/$a(.*)/", $b, $matches)){
    echo 'match Found';
} else {
    echo 'no match found';
}
```

But it does not do the job. Please help

Comment: @Vijay php would be my guess

Comment: Your code tests whether the entire contents of `$a` is anywhere in `$b`, and sets `$matches[1]` to everything after the matching part.

Comment: Your title says 4 characters, your question says 7 characters. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function instead of regex:

```
if( substr($a, 0, 4) === substr($b, 0, 4) ) echo "Matched!";
```

---

I'm not sure whether you want to match 4 characters or 7.

Comment: Sorry it should be 7 characters and it's in php